# Is there a way to order the subreports in a Crystal report

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports

--I have a crystal report with 4 subreports. I use a dataset with multiple tables as their datasources.

```
        Dim crystalreport As New frmCrystalViewer
        crystalreport.CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = rptReportDocument
        rptReportDocument.SetDataSource(dsReportSource.Tables("Reports"))

        Dim SubReportName As String
        If dsReportSource.Tables(0).Rows.Count > 0 Then
            If rptReportDocument.Subreports.Count > 0 Then
                For i = 0 To rptReportDocument.Subreports.Count - 1
                    If dsReportSource.Tables(i + 1).Rows.Count > 0 Then
                        SubReportName = rptReportDocument.Subreports(i).Name
                        rptReportDocument.Subreports(i).SetDataSource(dsReportSource.Tables(i + 1))
                    End If
                Next
            End If
        End If

        crystalreport.Show()
```

--Is there a way to order the subreports, (an index of some sort) so that my datatables match the subreports? They don't seem to have a specific order except creation order.

Thanks All

[MainReport](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GvbK7.png)

This is the main report. With two subreports. The dataset contains 3 datatables used to populate the main report(table1), subreport "policywording" (table2), subreport "perils" (table3). How do I order the subreports to load using the order of my tables so they map correctly. or index them per say... 0, 1, 2 etc

[Crystal Report showing sections](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0FyyM.png)

Datatable 0 is to main report. But datatable 1 is going to Sub report (2) and not sub report (1) for some reason. How do I switch load or listing order in report?

Comment: Do you mean order the rows of each subreports or do you mean to make one subreport show after or before another subreport based on some criteria?

Comment: One report show after another based on some sort of index or marker. In an order so the relevant tables match in my dataset.

Comment: Can you show what you get (screenshot), what you want, and your design?

Comment: thank you. i've added new image and text to my original post.

Comment: I can't see the section names in the image. And I'm still not understanding what is the final result that you want. What I can tell is that the subreports will show up in the order that you put in the designer. But depending on what are the sections that you are using, it can be tricky.

Comment: Hi Heringer. I think I may have solved my dilemma. Crystal loads reports based on SubreportName alphabetized.